# firebase/angularFire querying with startAt/endAt doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have an app where I use FirebaseSimpleLogin, but since I have additional user data, I store it under [my-firebase].firebaseio.com/users/[username]. The snippet below shows how it's done

```
 var User = {
    create: function (authUser, username) {

      users[username] = {
        md5_hash: authUser.md5_hash,
        username: username,
        email: authUser.email,
       $priority: authUser.uid
      };

      users.$save(username).then(function () {
        setCurrentUser(username);
      });

    },
    ...
```

Since data for each individual user, are keyed based on username I prioritize by uid, so I can later fetch additional user data by uid.

When the firebase login event fires, I have the following handler, that is responsible for querying firebase to get the additionala user data, and store it on $rootScope.currentUser via a method `setCurrentUser(username)`
**Here is my login event handler:**

```
var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + '/users');
var users = $firebase(ref);

$rootScope.$on('$firebaseSimpleLogin:login', function (e, authUser) {

      var query = $firebase(ref.startAt(authUser.uid).endAt(authUser.uid));

      query.$on('loaded', function () {
  //PROBLEM: console.log(query.$getIndex()) logs an empty array 
        setCurrentUser(query.$getIndex()[0]);
      });
});
```

As soon as the login event fires, I get access to the authUser, which contains the uid of the logged in user. Then I query firebase /users by uid, using startAt/endAt to limit my results so that I'm left only with the currently logged in user.

Then, when the query data is loaded from firebase, I invoke the `setCurrentUser` method which stores the username of the currentUser on $rootScope.

**The Problem**
The query filtering using startAt/endAt does not work, I'm getting back an empty array when I console.log `query.$getIndex()` when I should be getting an array with the username of the currently logged-in user.

I'm using firebase 1.0.15, angularFire 0.7.1 and firebase-simple-login 1.4.1 and following [this tutorial](http://www.thinkster.io/angularjs/4DYrJRxTyT/7-creating-your-own-user-data-using-firebase) from Thinkster.io

Comment: I was checking $priority, since there are some issues that caught my attention. It turns out that when User.create is called, .priority is set properly (export JSON from Forge), but as soon as I log out, the .priority key is no longer under the users/username firebase entry. Is this a bug?

Comment: If the priority is being removed ,then you must have an onDisconnect() or another op (another set() op that doesn't set priority? a transaction?) that is changing it.

Comment: No, I don't have another op changing the priority of the additional user data. 
Whenever I'm creating a user using the $createUSer method, I also create a /users/username entry (keyed by username) where I store additional user data. The latter is part of a User factory (singleton) and executes once. In no other place in my code I user either $priority or onDisconnect().

Answer (score 0):

In the end somewhere in my code I had a $save() on my user binding, to save the id of the last project they've been working on, and this was causing the $priority issue. I used $update instead, and now everything works like a charm!

Still I don't know if this is intended behavior of $save()
To clarify and provide more context, I wasn't passing any keys to the $save() method, I simply added a property on my local user reference, and  saved it

```
$rootScope.currentUser.lastWorkingProject = projectId;
$rootScope.currentUser.$save();
```